# Difficulty in deploying Node.JS + Grunt based web application from terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, grunt-cli

I have a website which is developed based on Node.JS and uses grunt to be run.

I want to deploy it on my aws server. So, i installed node.js and all its dependencies and modules, configured database etc, and i am able to run it from terminal.

First i used

```
grunt build
```

and then

```
grunt
```

and website is running and up without any problem.

My question is that how should i deploy these kind of websites, so it always is running and listening to the port? That is because whenever i close the terminal (Putty), it will stop working.

I tried using these commands to run it in the background but didn't work :

```
grunt &
```

alnd also

```
(grunt &)
```

but whenever i exit the terminal (putty) , web server stops working.

Can anybody please help me with that? How can i make grunt running even after closing the terminal?
And how node js + grunt websites will be deployed on the server in general?

Comment: Tried `screen` or [tmux](https://tmux.github.io/)?

Comment: Hello. Yes screen did the trick and i am happy with it now. However i am still wondering what is the professional approach for this and what approach is being used the most.